# How to add Subelements and its in xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a xml file which has subelements:-

```
.......
.......
<EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
    <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
         <UserName>xyz@xyz.com</UserName>
        <FeatureList>
                <FeatureDetail>
                <FeatureId>X</FeatureId>
                </FeatureDetail>
        </FeatureList>
    </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
</EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
.....
.....
```

I want to add a new sub element FeatureEntitlementDetail with all its subelements/children like username, Feature List, Feature Detail, Feature Id. I tried using  SubElement function, but it only adds FeatureEntitlementDetail />. The code which I used was :-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree  as ET
filename = "XYZ.xml"
xmlTree = ET.parse(filename)
root = xmlTree.getroot()
    for element in root.iter('EnabledFeatureListForUsers'):
        ET.SubElement(element,"FeatureEntitlementDetail")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When asking a question related to code, you need to add a tag for the language you're using. This helps get the question in front of people who are able to answer it, as well as making it available when people do searches based on that tag. Please [edit] your post to do so. Thanks.

Comment: update the post with the input xml and the output xml. Make sure they are **valid** docs

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
    <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
         <UserName>xyz@xyz.com</UserName>
        <FeatureList>
                <FeatureDetail>
                <FeatureId>X</FeatureId>
                </FeatureDetail>
        </FeatureList>
    </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
</EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

fed = ET.SubElement(root,'FeatureEntitlementDetail')
un = ET.SubElement(fed,'UserName')
un.text = 'abc.zz.net'
fl = ET.SubElement(fed,'FeatureList')
df = ET.SubElement(fl,'FeatureDetail')
fi = ET.SubElement(df,'FeatureId')
fi.text = 'Z'

ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
   <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
      <UserName>xyz@xyz.com</UserName>
      <FeatureList>
         <FeatureDetail>
            <FeatureId>X</FeatureId>
         </FeatureDetail>
      </FeatureList>
   </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
   <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
      <UserName>abc.zz.net</UserName>
      <FeatureList>
         <FeatureDetail>
            <FeatureId>Z</FeatureId>
         </FeatureDetail>
      </FeatureList>
   </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
</EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
```